# BAD ACCESS error when accessing method of vector element from touch callback

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a class structure as follows:

```
class A
{
 public:
     virtual void func() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
 public:
     virtual void func();
};
```

and **I have provided an implementation for B's func in the corresponding .cpp file.**

```
void B::func()
{
     cocos2d::log("Hello");
}
```

Now, when I try to access func of B from another file as follows:

```
class XYZ
{
 public:
    public void func2();
 protected:
    cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne * _Listener = nullptr;
    std::vector<A *> _List;

    bool touchBeginCallback(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event);
    void touchEndCallback(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event);
};
```

In XYZ.cpp

```
void XYZ::func2()
{
    _List.push_back(new B());
    _List.push_back(new B());
    _List.push_back(new B());
    _List.push_back(new B());
    _List.push_back(new B());

    for(auto itr = _List.begin(); itr != _List.end(); itr++)
    {
        A * a = (*itr);
        if(a)
        {
            a->func(); // Here it works fine
        }
    }

    _Listener = cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    _Listener->setSwallowTouches(true);
    _Listener->onTouchBegan = (cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::ccTouchBeganCallback) CC_CALLBACK_2(XYZ::touchBeginCallback, this);
    _Listener->onTouchEnded = (cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::ccTouchCallback) CC_CALLBACK_2(XYZ::touchEndCallback, this);

    cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(_Listener, this);
}

bool XYZ::touchBeginCallback(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    return true;
}

void XYZ::touchEndCallback(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    for(auto itr = _List.begin(); itr != _List.end(); itr++)
    {
        A *a = (*itr);
        if(a)
        {
            a->func(); // Throws bad access error
        }
    }
}
```

The func() call (or rather accessing object of type B) works fine if I call it from a method in XYZ, but crashes with BAD_ACCESS error if I call it from touchEndCallback method.

When I checked _List in debug mode *within func2()*, it correctly showed that _List had five members of **type B**, but when I checked the list *within touchEndCallback method*, it showed that _List had five members of **type A**.

Why is this crash happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: does the value of  `this` is same when `func2()` and `touchEndCallback()` is invoked?

Comment: @NishantSingh yes, it shows to be the same

Comment: @NishantSingh only difference is that _List is shown to have five members of type B within func2(), but it shows _List to have five members of type A within touchEndCallback()

Comment: use override keyword in B and ( * itr)->func() instead of iter->func(), because itr is semantically a pointer to vector elements and you have to dereference it to get the actual vector element which is a pointer (A*) in this case. also if you don't intend to use B as base class, then you dont need virtual in B

Comment: @StPiere you mean `virtual void func() override;` in class B? Unfortunately, this didnt help

Comment: We need a [mcve], at a guess your `XYZ` class has gone out of scope.

Comment: *it correctly showed that _List had five members of type B, but when I checked the list within touchEndCallback method, it showed that _List had five members of type A.* This should not happen unless there is some untelated bug in a different place. We need a [mcve] to proceed.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have updated my code example to include everything required to repro the crash. Please help.

Comment: @n.m. I have updated my code example to include everything required to repro the crash. Please help.

Comment: We must have different notions of "everything". I want to copy your code, pasre it to http://ideone.com and hit "run". If it compiles, runs, and produces the same run time error you are asking about, then you have everything.

Comment: @n.m. That would be difficult considering this might be a cocos2d platform specific issue. ideone.com doesn't seem to support cocos APIs

Comment: If I need to install an entire framework in order to help you, I'm afraid it won't happen. For one, my phone doesn't seem to support it. It is very unlikely to be a framework issue though. Perhaps try to isolate the errorbsuch that there is no framework dependency.

Comment: Yes I will try that and get back to you. Thanks a lot @n.m.

Comment: @n.m. turns out, the objects were getting destroyed for some reason before I touched it and triggered the callback. I refactored my design and now it works properly :) Thanks though :)

Comment: This is why we ask for a [mcve], the problem wasn't in the code posted which is why you couldn't find it and we couldn't find it either, sounds like my first guess was correct though ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereference the iterator to get the pointer A*.
The loop should look like this:

```
for(auto itr = _List.begin(); itr != _List.end(); itr++)
{
    if (*itr)
        (*itr)->func();
}
```

or you can use range for:

```
  for(auto pa : _List)  // now you're gettting A* 's directly
    {
        if (pa)
           pa->func();    
    }
```

EDIT: Using raw pointers is also bad idea. consider **unique_ptr** or **shared_ptr**.
If you still have an error, it could be that you are deleting objects on some other place so the List is containing invalid pointers. But without full code is hard to say what is happening. If the objects are getting deleted on some other place, than you'de need to set List's A*'s to nullptr explicitetly, otherwise if (a) would still evaluate to true.

Comment: I have edited my question to include this, but issue still persists.

Comment: You Still have error: ( * iter) is A* and not A , because your List is holdint A* 's

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that's what I meant as the current state of my code. i have edited my code. Issue still exists

Comment: Tried the range approach too, it didn't help :(

Comment: turns out, the objects were getting destroyed for some reason  before I touched it and triggered the callback. I refactored my design and now it works properly :)

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the issue